# Mongodb C# driver An exception occurred while sending a message to the server

Tags: c#, mongodb, webapi

I got below exception while try to update data in mongodb. Please help me to fix this issue.

When I look in my logs I see lot of error messages just like the one below where the driver is getting a socket error when connecting to mongo. The site is still up and this error doesn't happen on every request, nor does it happen on one operation that should take longer.

The version I have used **C# driver : "2.10.2" and Azure Cosmos version :3.6".**

MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while sending a message to the server. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartWriting(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.StreamExtensionMethods.WriteBytes(Stream stream, IByteBuffer buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.SendBuffer(IByteBuffer buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.SendBuffer(IByteBuffer buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.SendMessages(IEnumerable`1 messages, MessageEncoderSettings messageEncoderSettings, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.ConnectionPools.ExclusiveConnectionPool.AcquiredConnection.SendMessages(IEnumerable`1 messages, MessageEncoderSettings messageEncoderSettings, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionExtensions.SendMessage(IConnection connection, RequestMessage message, MessageEncoderSettings messageEncoderSettings, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingCommandMessageWireProtocol`1.Execute(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.Execute(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.Server.ServerChannel.ExecuteProtocol[TResult](IWireProtocol`1 protocol, ICoreSession session, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.Server.ServerChannel.Command[TResult](ICoreSession session, ReadPreference readPreference, DatabaseNamespace databaseNamespace, BsonDocument command, IEnumerable`1 commandPayloads, IElementNameValidator commandValidator, BsonDocument additionalOptions, Action`1 postWriteAction, CommandResponseHandling responseHandling, IBsonSerializer`1 resultSerializer, MessageEncoderSettings messageEncoderSettings, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.RetryableWriteCommandOperationBase.ExecuteAttempt(RetryableWriteContext context, Int32 attempt, Nullable`1 transactionNumber, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.RetryableWriteOperationExecutor.Execute[TResult](IRetryableWriteOperation`1 operation, RetryableWriteContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.BulkUnmixedWriteOperationBase`1.ExecuteBatch(RetryableWriteContext context, Batch batch, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.BulkUnmixedWriteOperationBase`1.ExecuteBatches(RetryableWriteContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.BulkUnmixedWriteOperationBase`1.Execute(RetryableWriteContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.BulkMixedWriteOperation.ExecuteBatch(RetryableWriteContext context, Batch batch, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.BulkMixedWriteOperation.Execute(IWriteBinding binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.OperationExecutor.ExecuteWriteOperation[TResult](IWriteBinding binding, IWriteOperation`1 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.ExecuteWriteOperation[TResult](IClientSessionHandle session, IWriteOperation`1 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.BulkWrite(IClientSessionHandle session, IEnumerable`1 requests, BulkWriteOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<BulkWrite>b__0(IClientSessionHandle session) at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSession[TResult](Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.BulkWrite(IEnumerable`1 requests, BulkWriteOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionBase`1.<>c__DisplayClass92_0.b__0(IEnumerable`1 requests, BulkWriteOptions bulkWriteOptions) at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionBase`1.UpdateMany(FilterDefinition`1 filter, UpdateDefinition`1 update, UpdateOptions options, Func`3 bulkWrite) at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionBase`1.UpdateMany(FilterDefinition`1 filter, UpdateDefinition`1 update, UpdateOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Sensiple.Tryvium.Data.MongoDB.CommonConnector.Update(String schemaName, String dataFilter, String data, String logSource)

Code that causes issue,

```
var _collection = Db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(schemaName); 

BsonDocument bsonDocument = new BsonDocument(BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(dataFilter)); 

var updatedResult = _collection.UpdateMany(bsonDocument, BsonDocument.Parse("{$set: " + BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(data) + "}"));
```

Comment: Please provide the code where you are getting the exception

Comment: @viveknuna,  Please find my code below. While execute update I got that exception.


var _collection = Db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(schemaName);
                        BsonDocument bsonDocument = new BsonDocument(BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(dataFilter));
                        var updatedResult = _collection.UpdateMany(bsonDocument, BsonDocument.Parse("{$set: " + BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(data) + "}"));

Comment: I think size limit is the issue

Comment: @viveknuna, the size of data is around 2 kb.

Comment: That error tells you `An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host` - what do the logs at the other end tell you?

Comment: @Joe, after this exception the next update statement executed fine without any issue. Is there anything specifically needs to be mentioned in connection string or cosmos db settings to rid of this issue?

Comment: After the exception the problem connection would have been dropped from the pool, so the next update would use a different one.

Comment: thanks @Joe, This is happening per day 4 -6 times per day in production. What can I do to fix this issue.

Comment: The first step will be identifying why the connection was closed.  Have your application make a log entry whenever a connection is created, and compare with the logs from the mongod node.  If it was the mongod that closed the connection, it will log why.  If it wasn't closed by either the mongod or the application, you may need to examine the networking setup.

Comment: Thanks @Joe for your prompt response. At present I don't have log while create mongo connection. First I will add log in that location.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue (which probably started when we upgraded from Cosmos 3.2 to 3.6/4.0), and **the fix was to set/force TLS 1.2** (based on [this Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-mongodb-dotnet)):

```cs
//return new MongoClient(connectionString);
var settings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString(connectionString);
settings.SslSettings = new SslSettings()
{
    EnabledSslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12
};
return new MongoClient(settings);
```